# How are TableView styled?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

[image]

As shown in the figure, the problem is the bottom right corner of the table. I wanted to change the color of the white square to blue, but I couldn't. I tried to style the `ScrollPane`, but it didn't seem to work. Is the style of the white block controlled by `ScrollPane`?

CSS:

```css
/*******************************************************************************
 *                                                                             *
 * ScrollPane                                                                  *
 *                                                                             *
 ******************************************************************************/
.scroll-pane{
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;
}
.scroll-pane > .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;
}
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 1 1, 1;
    -fx-padding: 0 1 0 1;
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal > .increment-button,
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.25em 0.25em  0.25em; /* 2 3 3 3 */
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button,
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em 0.166667em; /* 3 3 3 2 */
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
.scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
.scroll-pane > .corner {
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 1 0;

}
/* new styleclass for edge to edge scrollpanes that don't want to draw a border */
.scroll-pane.edge-to-edge,
.tab-pane > * > .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
.scroll-pane.edge-to-edge > .scroll-bar,
.tab-pane > * > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar,
.titled-pane > .content > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
.scroll-pane.edge-to-edge > .scroll-bar > .increment-button,
.scroll-pane.edge-to-edge > .scroll-bar > .decrement-button,
.tab-pane > * > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar > .increment-button,
.tab-pane > * > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar > .decrement-button,
.titled-pane > .content > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar > .increment-button,
.titled-pane > .content > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3px */
    -fx-background-color: #30466B;

}
```

Comment: A tableView/Skin (more precisely: its VirtualFlow) has no scrollPane but manages the scrollBars/content manually - that's why styling a scrollPane has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corner box is defined with the styleClass "corner". you need to override the below css implementation for tableView:

```
.table-view > .virtual-flow > .corner {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-base,-1%);
}
```